# How to align a counter in html

Tags: html, alignment, counter

I have a counter in my html code. I want to align this counter in the middle of the site. There is a helper class, called text-align which works with almost all objects on the site but i don't know how to align a script entry.

My code looks like this:

```
<section class="wow fadeIn">
    <div class="container-fluid full-screen position-relative no-padding no-transition" >
           <div class="opacity-medium bg-white"></div>
           <div id="animated-balls"></div>
           <div class="slider-typography xs-position-inherit">
               <div class="slider-text-middle-main">
                   <div class="slider-text-top slider-text-middle2">
                       <!-- logo -->
                       <div class="coming-soon-logo"><img class="logo-style-2" src="images/offene-stadt.png" alt=""/></div>
                       <!-- end logo -->
                       <span class="coming-soon-title text-uppercase gray-text margin-ten no-margin-lr no-margin-bottom">We're getting ready to launch</span>
                       <!-- time -->
                       <div id="counter-underconstruction2" class="white-text text-center margin-two no-margin-lr no-margin-bottom"></div>
                       <div id="countdown-target" class="text-center"></div>
                       <script>
                       var myCountdown1 = new Countdown({time:86400*20});
                       </script>
                    </div>

                       <!-- end time -->
```

Comment: What is the countdown script you're using? It might have docs that let you point it at an existing placeholder tag

Comment: Could you please add a jsfiddle (or add more code here)

Comment: where do you use myCountdown1?

Comment: what is a jsfiddle? the script i am using ist this: http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown/

Comment: i didn't found something in the docs. i can host the page on github if that helps. my countdown or the countdown is shown on the left of the site and seems to be stuck there wherelse the other elements (like the anchor and text) are in the middle

Comment: @Lukas https://jsfiddle.net/ its where you set up a working copy of your problem so we can try to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `target` to point it at a specific item so try this:

```
               <div class="slider-text-top slider-text-middle2">
                   <!-- logo -->
                   <div class="coming-soon-logo"><img class="logo-style-2" src="images/logo-light-big.png" alt=""/></div>
                   <!-- end logo -->
                   <span class="coming-soon-title text-uppercase gray-text margin-ten no-margin-lr no-margin-bottom">We're getting ready to launch</span>
                   <!-- time -->
                   <div id="counter-underconstruction2" class="white-text text-center margin-two no-margin-lr no-margin-bottom"></div>
                   <i class="icon-anchor medium-icon"></i>
                   <div id="countdownTarget" class="center-block"></div>
                   <script>
                   var myCountdown1 = new Countdown({time:316, target: "countdownTarget"});
                   </script>
                   <!-- end time -->
               </div>
```

And then use your existing `text-align` technique on the `#countdownTarget` to position it how you like.

Comment: <div id="countdown-target" class="text-center"></div> if that div box is closed right away, how does it interact with something under that box? Anyways.. that technique with center does not seem to work there.

Comment: I've updated the snippet, try `center-block`, assuming you're using bootstrap?

Comment: It interacts because the javascript looks up the div with `id="countdownTarget"` and then puts the countdown markup inside of it.